# How can I call a service within a pipe?

Tags: angular

There is a way to inject and call a service within a pipe? I have a service with currencies and I want to use it to get the name based on the id. 
Thanks!!

This is my code:

```js
@Pipe({name: 'currencypipe', pure: false})
export class CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    symbol: string = null;

    constructor(private currencyService: CurrencyService) {

    }

    transform(value: number, currencyId: number): Promise<String> {
        return this.currencyService.getCurrencie(currencyId).then(response => {
                return (value + " " + response.symbol);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And I use it like this

```js
{{3 | currencypipe: 2 | async}}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You may inject service in pipes like you do in any component,

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'my-currency-pipe'
})
export class MyCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(service: SomeService) {
       
    }

    transform(value: string): string {
        return value;
    }
}
```

However you may also use Parameter in pipes. [Read more here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)

**Update**

[excerpts from Pipe documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) search for *An impure caching pipe*,

> Let's write one more impure pipe, a pipe that makes an HTTP request to
> the server. Normally, that's a horrible idea. It's probably a horrible
> idea no matter what we do. We're forging ahead anyway to make a point.
> Remember that impure pipes are called every few microseconds. If we're
> not careful, this pipe will punish the server with requests.

Keeping above in mind, you can do below for your scenario to get result asynchronously,

```js
import { Component, PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

export class CurrencyService  {
  getCurrencie(currencyId):Promise<string> {
     return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
         if(currencyId === 1 ){
            resolve({symbol : '$'});
         }else{
           resolve({symbol: '£'});
         }
       }, 1000)
     })
  }
}

@Pipe({name: 'currencypipe', pure: false})
export class CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    symbol: string = null;
    prevalue: string = null;
    result: string = '';
    
    constructor(private currencyService: CurrencyService) {
    }

    transform(value: number, currencyId: number) {
      if (value !== this.prevalue) {
         this.prevalue = value;
         this.result = '';
         
         this.currencyService.getCurrencie(currencyId).then(response => {                   
                this.result = value + " " + response.symbol;
            }
        );
      }
       return this.result;
    }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Currency Pipe</h1>
   <hr />
   {{3 | currencypipe: 1 }}
  `
})
export class AppComponent { }

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CurrencyPipe ],
  providers: [ CurrencyService ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Here is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QmL9BVtxw8RE4emIDrL9?p=preview)!!

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but how can I return a value mixing data using the service. I tried setting pure:false for make a async pipe and returing a promise, but hangs the browser.

Comment: You can return a promise or observable. You need to chain the pipe with the `async` pipe like `{{someVal | my-currency-pipe | async}}` or ``{{(someVal | my-currency-pipe | async)?.someField}}`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I added the code to the question, I tried `{{someVal | my-currency-pipe | async}}` but still hanging the browser.

Comment: @DiegoGonzález: updated answer have a look, Cheers!!

Comment: @MadhuRanjan Ok that work, thanks! So the key is to set something in this case `prevalue` to avoid creating a new Promise and enter in a loop?

Comment: Just to note, as this pipe is impure it's probably called at least 12 times on view instantiation, and again on every tick of change detector